# Haskell any way to improve this code

Tags: performance, haskell

Hey I have implemented this code segment as a move ordering system for a alpha-beta pruning function. It does speed up my code by a little but when I profiled my code I saw it was very clunky.

```
    move_ord [] (primary_ord,secondary_ord) = primary_ord ++ secondary_ord 
    move_ord (y:ys) (primary_ord,secondary_ord) = case no_of_pebbles state y of
        0        -> move_ord ys (primary_ord,secondary_ord)
        13       -> move_ord ys (y : primary_ord,secondary_ord)
        x        
            | 7 - y == x -> move_ord ys (y : primary_ord,secondary_ord)
            | otherwise     -> move_ord ys (primary_ord,y : secondary_ord)
```

It is meant to place moves with specific pebble values (13 and 7-y==x) at the front of the list. While also filtering out illegal moves of 0 pebbles.

Pebbles are stored as Int. y is a Int.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is `state` in `no_of_pebbles state y` and what does `no_of_pebbles` do (does it in any way depend on `primary_ord` and `secondary_ord`)?

Comment: Try removing `primary_ord` and `secondary_ord` from the tuple and instead make them two separate arguments to `move_ord`.  That *might* improve the constant factors.  However, I think if you really want to improve speed you may need to reconsider your overarching algorithm, perhaps by storing the moves in a data structure other than a list.

Comment: State is the current board it is a record of several different values. no_of_pebbles extracts the amount of pebbles associated with the pot specified.

Comment: Does the order in which the elements of `primary_ord` appear matter?

Comment: No it does not. I am ordering branches to check first for alpha-beta cutoffs. The cases I outlined have a higher probability of triggering a pruning on the next branch evaluated. Though since I have no other information they can be in any order as long as they appear in front of the other cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the order in which the elements of `primary_ord` appear matter?
>
> No it does not. I am ordering branches to check first for alpha-beta cutoffs. The cases I outlined have a higher probability of triggering a pruning on the next branch evaluated. Though since I have no other information they can be in any order as long as they appear in front of the other cases.

In that case, you should deliver the good ones as soon as you find them, and only defer delivering the bad ones.

If `move_ord` is - except in the recursive calls - only called with `([],[])` as the second argument, I'd recommend

```
move_ord = go []
  where
    go acc (y:ys) = case no_of_pebbles state y of
                      0             -> go acc ys
                      13            -> y : go acc ys
                      x | x == 7-y  -> y : go acc ys
                        | otherwise -> go (y:acc) ys
    go acc _ = acc
```

Thus a) you can run in smaller space (unless the consumer accumulates the entire result) and b) the consumer need not wait for the entire list to be traversed before it can start working.

Of course, if there are only very few or even none "good" `y`s, it may not make a difference, and if the consumer needs the entire list before it can do anything neither. But usually, that should improve matters somewhat. Otherwise, there is not much that can be done in this function, `no_of_pebbles` would be what uses the most resources here.

If `move_ord` can be called with non-empty `primary_ord` or `secondary_ord`, use a wrapper

```
move_ord xs (primary, secondary) = primary ++ go secondary xs
  where
    go acc ...  -- as above
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am currently testing your code. Earlier tests were promising.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that `move_ord` starts out being called as `move_ord ys ([], [])`. We then have a streaming filter pattern on `Either`.

```
import Data.Either

sorter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [Either a a]
sorter p = map go where go x = if p x then Left x else Right x
```

then,

```
uncurry (++) 
. partitionEithers
. sorter (\x -> no_of_pebbles x == 13 || 7 - x == no_of_pebbles x) 
. filter (\x -> no_of_pebbles x != 0)
```

Which is still a little ugly because we keep computing `no_of_pebbles` in various places. This might be alright for documentation purposes, but we could also precompute `no_of_pebbles`.

```
uncurry (++)
. partitionEithers
. sorter (\(x, num) -> num == 13 || 7 - x == num)
. filter ((!=0) . snd)
. map (\x -> (x, no_of_pebbles x))
```

Comment: When I tried using your method it was actually slower than my original code. Thank you for trying though.

Comment: This code is definitely nicer and more Haskellish. Too bad its not faster. Maybe list fusion is not kicking in completely?

Comment: Oh! I was trying for composability instead of optimization. I misread the question—but still feel like list fusion should help to make this whole thing a bit faster. Perhaps doing things a bit more explicitly with `pipes` could work.

Answer (score 0):

### Specialization.

As you use literal constant the compiler will infer default Integer type not Int.
Then you need to specialize the type signature of your function, like so.

```
move_ord :: [Int] -> ([Int], [Int]) -> ([Int], [Int])
```

### Memoization.

Your input list can contain duplicate element, then two strategy are possible.
Memoize your call of no_of_pebbles, it will save you extract computation, or you can sort and remove the duplicate of your input list before processing it.

### Return a tuple.

You accumulate the response as a tuple then maybe you should return it as is.
Trying to merge the two element of it into the function seems to be out of scope.
Should be manage later in your code, and it's good to know that list store in tuple are common data type know as dlist.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I will look into your advice.